# Graph for toggling data set

Tags: info-visualisation, toggle, data-analysis

We are building a network monitoring tool and we need to show a graph which shows the Active/Inactive state of the machines.

Like for example, during a period of 24 hours, during which periods the machine was down. The series values would be either ACTIVE or DEAD. And this series is laid over a time axis of 24 hours.

Can anyone suggest the graph which will help depict this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to show them all at once? Show an overview of 10,000 machines? What level of resolution is needed? These all affect how you would likely display them.

Comment: No. For each individual machine. For consolidated, we are planning to show the count of the machines which are active and inactive. So, I think a simple bar graph would suffice.

Comment: It sounds like a simple manhattan (vertical bar) graph would work here.

Comment: I guess vertical bar graph should be good for consolidated count graph. I am asking for Active/Inactive graph over the period of 24 hours for a specific machine. The series values would be either ````ACTIVE```` or ````DEAD````. And this series is laid over a time axis of 24 hours.

Comment: If you only have 2 states, then just represent one of them and show the graph from 0 - 100%.  The other state is clear from that one.

Comment: So, you suggest a line graph which is quite like a digital signal curve over the time axis, right? Is't there any other way to represent this?

Comment: What is the frequency of your status-polling? Once a minute? And what is the maximum number of data points that you want to show at a time? Will you be rolling up the data (averaging per hour etc.)? Shouldn't you be measuring up-time instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use bar graph if the value is boolean, use colors on a timeline.

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty interesting. Great work there. Thanks.

Comment: Any graph API which can generate the above graph? Which one did you use to create it?

Comment: It's handmade using Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: @divinedragon check out my answer for automation using Google Graph API

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Andy's graphic for the graph you could then use Google Graph API to create a less pretty, but automated version of this:

[image: Graph using Google Graph API]

This was created using the following code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Status', 'On', 'Off'],
        ['12am',  1,   0],
        ['1am',  1,   0],
        ['2am',  1,   0],
        ['3am',  0,   1],
        ['4am',  1,   0],
        ['5am',  1,   0],
        ['6am',  1,   0],
        ['7am',  1,   0],
        ['8am',  1,   0],
        ['9am',  1,   0],
        ['10am',  1,   0],
        ['11am',  1,   0],
        ['12pm',  1,   0],
        ['13pm',  1,   0],
        ['14pm',  1,   0],
        ['15pm',  1,   0],
        ['16pm',  1,   0],
        ['17pm',  1,   0],
        ['6pm',  1,   0],
        ['19pm',  1,   0],
        ['20pm',  1,   0],
        ['21pm',  1,   0],
        ['22pm',  1,   0],
        ['23pm',  1,   0],
        ['12am',  1,   0],
      ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
     draw(data,
               { width:600, height:100, 
                 chartArea: {height:20},
               colors: ['#8ac244','#db1b1c'],
                hAxis: {allowContainerBoundaryTextCufoff:true, showTextEvery:6},
                vAxis: {gridlines:{count:0}},
                bar: {groupWidth:16},
                isStacked:true
               }
          );
}
```

​
And you can test the code here: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart

Comment: This answer, while potentially useful, isn't really a separate answer, it's an implementation guide for Andys answer. UX is technology-agnostic, so answers including implementation instructions and code are best left to other StackExchange sites. We'll leave this here for now because it has been well-received but this shouldn't be a standard method of answering questions on this site . (We don't want to get bogged-down with code implementation here, and each answer should be a different and separate response to the question, not just commentary on others).

Comment: Hey @JonW yes is was only because the author commented on the answer asking "Any graph API which can generate the above graph?"